# Defining a model structure through weak equivalences and fibrations

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a complete and cocomplete category, and assume I have a set $W$ of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ which is closed under retracts and satisfies the 2-out-of-3 property. Assume now that I have another set $F$ of morphisms, also closed under retracts. Is there a characterization of the properties that I need on $F$ so that it is the set of fibrations in a model structure on $\mathcal{C}$ with $W$ as the set of weak equivalences (with cofibrations defined by lifting property)?

I know that many will think of fibrantly generated model categories reading this question, but I would like $F$ to be the whole set of fibrations, and not just a set generating them (as morphisms with the lifting property with respect to the cofibrations).

Also, please specify what axioms you are using in the definition of model category. I am using the ones found in the paper *On PL De Rham theory and rational homotopy type* by Bousfield and Gugenheim, that are equivalent to the ones originally given by Quillen for closed categories, but I'm not averse to using slightly different axioms (e.g. requiring/implying functoriality of the factorizations of morphisms, as in Goerss-Jardine if I'm not mistaken).